# How to import bulk of data in Magento

Tags: php, magento

How to import bulk of data in Magento. I tried many times but I did not import a single file. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Describe what you have try and what error you faced?

Comment: The best option to import big (ten or hundred of thousands products) is to use Pimgento. Initially it's built to import from the Akeneo PIM but the csv structure it requires is nice and it's very fast. If not bulk importing in Magento due to the EAV structure is very complicated and that is where pimgento is really practical.

Comment: When I try for magmi. It gives sku error. and The zip file of PiGmento gives error during installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods to import bulk data in Magento.

**Method 1**

```
    a). Login Your admin panel -> system -> Import/Export -> Import 
    b). In Entity Type, select according to choice.
    c). In Import Behavior, select according to choice.
    d). In Select File to Import, select your csv.
    e). Click on check data button in the top part of right side.
    f). After that click on Import.
```

**Method 2**

```
    a). Login Your admin panel -> system -> Import/Export -> Dataflow-Profiles
    b). Click on Import Customers to import customer data.
    c). Click on Import Product Stocks to import product stocks.
    d). Click on Import All Products to import products.
    e). Click on Upload File and choose your CSV file.
    f). Click on Save and Continue Edit button in right side top.
    g). Click on Run Profile and select CSV file.
    h). Click on Run Profile in Popup to start importing.
```

Comment: Yea, Its working. Can you please tell me how to solve this problem. When i import some csv file it gives error "required sku field is not defined". I try many ways to solve this error by searching on internet but it's not working. Can you please help?

Answer (score -1):

You can import products and customers according to magento data format (Import).

Otherwise, you need to create a file including the fields that you need to import - you can use Data profiles option.